# Clone only text of row and add in after current row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, addition, insertafter

So I have a header row in my table that has inputs and the ability to add a new row from this information. I cannot clone the exact header row, because I do not want the select/inputs/buttons...just the text/val. How can I go about doing this? My fiddle is pretty plain at the moment, but the setup is in place (I don't actually want "new" added, I want the values from the header row) http://jsfiddle.net/9dwdz30h/

**jQuery**

```
$('.addRow').click(function(){
     $('.header').after('<tr><td>new</td></tr>')
})
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class='header'>
        <th>
            <input type='text' />
        </th>
        <th>
            <select>
                <option>One</option>
                <option>Two</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#" class="addRow">Add</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want ONLY to add the select value to the row you can do it like that:

```
$('.addRow').click(function(){
     $('.header').after('<tr><td>'+$("select").val()+'</td></tr>')
})
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/294tkjn2/

OR you can also add input:

```
$('.addRow').click(function(){
     $('.header').after('<tr><td>'+$("input").val()+" "+$("select").val()+'</td></tr>')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you were looking for `$('table').append()`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dapLf9hz/

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not have the text input value.

Answer (score 0):

This will grab the value from the text box and add it to the top

```
 $('.addRow').click(function(){
     $('.header').after('<tr><td>'+$('#new').val()+'</td></tr>')
 })
```

also add an id="new" to your text box

```
<th>
    <input type='text' id="new" />
</th>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/294tkjn2/1/